# hoisting prototype at top of the code

Tags: javascript

variables in a functions are hoisted at top but outside it is not hoisted at the top of the code:

```
function myFunc(){
//..
}
var m1 = new myFunc();
console.log(m1.test);//logs undefined
myFunc.prototype.test = 'testing';
console.log(m1.test);//now logs testing
```

**Question:** Is there any way to behaving hoist the prototype at top so that first log in above code would log 'testing' instead of undefined?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question as it is quite hard to understand what it is that you are asking.

Comment: logs undefined should log testing

Comment: umm, cut and paste the line myFunc.prototype.test = 'testing'; to underneath the function myFunc(){} ???

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how hoisting works. A hoisted **function declaration** can be used before it's declared but function expressions and variables hoist the variable identifier, but with a value of `undefined` until the assignment occurs. Your expression is neither of those, no hoisting occurs.

Comment: yeah no hositing occurs but I wanted to make and behave as it is hoisting from top.

Comment: You can't. You're facing an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I wanted to do this so that anywhere if added prototype then it would be defined anywhere.....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you maybe post a more practical example?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Its better not to add prototype methods in different places.

Comment: I think this is a code organization issue. Put your constructor function in one file, then put all your prototype methods in another (or seperate files) and then make sure that the constructor and prototype files are included first before any other code.

Answer (score 0):

if you really have such requirement, you can do

```
function log(obj, attr) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }, 0);
}

function myFunc(){
    //..
}
var m1 = new myFunc();
log(m1, 'testing'); // now logs testing

myFunc.prototype.test = 'testing';
log(m1, 'testing'); // now logs testing
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem (in my case, wanting to hoist a prototype function that's defined after it's called), and this is how I did it:

```
var m1 = new myFunc();
console.log(m1.test); // 'testing'

/////////////////////////////////

function myFunc () {
  myFuncBuilder.prototype.test = 'testing';
  myFuncBuilder.prototype.definedLater = definedLater;

  return new myFuncBuilder();
}

function myFuncBuilder () {
  // ...
}

function definedLater () {
  // ...
}
```

I agree with the other people though; this probably isn't a good way to organize code.